# Do reflection and diffraction occur at the same time?

Tags: waves, reflection, diffraction

[image]

When waves pass through a gap as the above, diffraction occurs.

As the upper and lower part of the plane wave (indicated by yellow colour) are striking the barriers, does reflection occur at the same time? Is this the cause of the decrease in amplitude when diffraction occurs?

Comment: I have done some experiments that relate to your question. I’ve found that reflection and diffraction “mirror” each other. I have not been able to create an experiment where this is not the case. I am not a professionally trained physicist, but nevertheless I think there is value in them https://youtu.be/lELlRpmGOYE https://youtu.be/wNRxMMABJQI

Answer (score 2):

You can design the barriers such that wave hitting them is absorbed other than reflected (Key word: impedance matching). The reason why decrease in amplitude in the diffracted wave happens, is not because of reflection, but because of the portion of the wave that passed the opening now has to occupy wider wave front than before.